Existence of monotonically increasing surjection onto closed set of $\mathbb{R}$
I am studying Measure Theory using the book by Elstrodt and there is an exercise in the chapter on measures on $\mathbb{R}$ I am struggling with.
Exercise: For every non-empty closed set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists a monotonically increasing function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(\mathbb{R}) = A$.
To be honest I don't even know how to approach the problem. I had the following idea for countable sets $A$: In this case we can construct a bijection $g$ between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ that respects the natural order on $\mathbb{R}$ and define $f(x) = g(1)$ for $x \leq 0$ and $f(x) = g(k+1)$ for $x \in ]k,k+1]$.
But what if $A$ is uncountable? I somehow need to use the fact that $A$ is closed and I am not sure whether I actually need any measure-theoretic arguments for this exercise (in the end the exercise must be in this chapter for some reason. Every monotonically increasing function defines a content on the semi-ring $\mathfrak{J} := \{\ ]a,b]\ :\  a \leq b,\ a,b \in \mathbb{R}\  \}$, but I don't really see how that might be any helpful here.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me get started or lead the way.
Thanks a lot!

What can you say about the connected components of $A$?

@julio_es_sui_glace They should be limit points I think. Every point of $A$ is either a limit point or an isolated point.

What do you mean by monotonically increasing? Do you simply mean "increasing", i.e. $x\ge y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge f(y)$?

@MoisheKohan The book is in German and not explicit about this, but I think the function does not have to be strictly increasing.

I don't see how you get that $f$ is monotonic in your countable case. For example, if $A={0,1}\cup{\frac1n\mid n\in \mathbb N^+}\cup{1-\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N^+},$ the ordering of,$A$ is not one that can be enumerated as a we;l-ordering.

Let $f(x)=\inf{a\in A\mid a\geq x}.$

@MoisheKohan "Monotonically increasing" is used to mean not-necessarily strictly increasing. "Increasing" alone might mean $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y).$

We can define
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
\max A & \text{ if $A$ is bounded above and $x > \max A$,}  \\
 \min (A \cap [x, \infty)) & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The minimum exists because $A \cap [x, \infty)$ is closed and bounded below. Then $f(x) \in A$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, and $f(x) = x$ for $x \in A$, so that $f(\Bbb R) = A$.
Remark: Such a function $f$ can not be strictly increasing unless $A = \Bbb R$: Assume that $f$ is strictly increasing onto a closed set $A$. According to If $F$ is strictly increasing with closed image, then $F$ is continuous, $f$ is continuous. Then $A = f(\Bbb R)$ is both open and closed. Since $\Bbb R$ is connected, it follows that $A = \Bbb R$.

Thanks a lot for your answer. I also thought that you just need to start somewhere and then sort of pick the next biggest element of $A$, but for uncountable sets you obviously cannot label the elements. This is basically what the minimum achieves here, clever!

Define $f(a) = a$ for all $a\in A$. Let's extend this to to an increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $A$. The complement of $A$ is a disjoint union of open intervals with ends in $A$ or $\pm \infty$. On each such interval define $f$ to be constant one of the ends that is in $A$.
